# Drobox API Upload Not Working For Business Users

Tags: vb.net, http, upload, dropbox-api

Earlier i have used Dropbox api on personal user account and all goes very fine.

Now, i need to do the same, but this time account is a business account user. I have tried for hours but can't find a working way to upload the file.

Here is my code that i tried:

```
objDHTTP = New Chilkat.Http
objDHTTP.UnlockComponent("")
objDHTTP.HeartbeatMs = 125
objDHTTP.ConnectTimeout = 60
objDHTTP.ReadTimeout = 60

objDJSON = New Chilkat.JsonObject
objDJSON.AppendString("path", "/test.pdf")
objDJSON.AppendString("mode", "overwrite")
objDJSON.AppendBool("autorename", False)
objDJSON.AppendBool("mute", True)

objDRequest = New Chilkat.HttpRequest
objDRequest.UsePost()
objDRequest.Path = "/2/files/upload"
objDRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
objDRequest.AddHeader("Dropbox-API-Select-User", "dbmid:member_id") 'Note-1
objDRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer auth_token") 'Note-2
objDRequest.AddHeader("Dropbox-API-Arg", objDJSON.Emit)
objDRequest.StreamBodyFromFile(strLocalFile)
objDResponse = objDHTTP.SynchronousRequest("content.dropboxapi.com", 443, True, objDRequest)
objDJSON.Dispose()
objDJSON = Nothing
If (objDResponse Is Nothing) Then
    strDBReturn = "Call failed!"
Else
    strDBReturn = objDResponse.BodyStr.Trim
    objDResponse.Dispose()
    objDResponse = Nothing
End If
objDRequest.Dispose()
objDRequest = Nothing
```

Code is in vb.net and i use chilkat libray for http and json part.
but it's very easy to understand the code.

Note-1: i have set the header to select member.

Note-2: first i tried Dropbox API, then i am tring Dropbox Business API

it's shows in the response that file is upload and also shows the same path as the http request.. but i can't find the file in the Dropbox (from browser) :(

Here is the DB Response Example:

```
{"name": "test1.pdf", "path_lower": "/test1.pdf", "path_display": "/test1.pdf", "id": "id:7fQPQ7pubtAAAAAAAAAAFQ", "client_modified": "2018-10-01T13:46:24Z", "server_modified": "2018-10-01T13:46:24Z", "rev": "cee6f9f90", "size": 204181, "content_hash": "318bc8a4b25c3c319b558dda011a8e837caa0dee2b84e1c7deb0d0405bad1bf0"}
```

any help will be highly appreciated..

thanks in advance
best regards

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but Dropbox offers a [.NET SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet). It's much easier and works very well in my experience. Why don't you use it?

Comment: Can you share the response you get? Also, you are uploading to a specific team member's account, via `Dropbox-API-Select-User`. Can you double check that you're looking at the right account on web?

Comment: @Greg, dear sir thanks a lot for your kind response. Yes, i have looking into same/correct user account/folders :) And as you asked, i have added the the DB response.

Comment: @Zakir_SZH Thanks! That output does indicate that the file was uploaded successfully. Based on the lack of sharing metadata it should be directly in the member's own folder. We'll follow up with you privately to help you locate it.

Comment: @Greg, that would be so kind of you. Any estimated time? as my time zone is far away from yours. mine is GMT+6.00 and i am online form 10am to 9pm.

Comment: @Zakir_SZH We replied to the Dropbox support ticket about this yesterday. If you did not see that, please contact us here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact